# Why isn't the TensorFlow's optimizer object recognized?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to put together a reinforcement learning algorithm from scratch using proximal policy optimization. The problem I'm facing is my graph optimizer object isn't being recognized when I try to call it using {session.run()}. The error I'm getting is "NameError: name 'optimizer' is not defined". I'm trying to call from a method located within the class where the LSTM network is defined. I do effectively the same thing from another class to get predictions from the network and that works but I don't understand why this call doesn't work.

```
def __init__(self, input_size, output_size, session):
    """
    input_size: dimension of input environment - OpenAI cartpole = 4
    output_size: dimension of action space - OpenAI cartpole = 2
    """
    # LSTM expects input to be 3D Tensor
    # Reshape input for LSTM
    self.env = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, None, input_size])
    #self.environment = tf.reshape(self.env, shape=[1, None, input_size])

    #obsp = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,])
    #delta = tf.reshape(obsp, shape=[1, 1, 4])

    self.lstm1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8, return_sequences=False)(self.env)
    # Softmax returns probabilty distribution of actions and what NN predicts will be best
    self.actor = tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation="softmax")(self.lstm1)
    self.critic = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None)(self.lstm1)

    return_ = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
    actor_loss = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
    entropy = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

    critic_loss = (return_ - self.critic)**2
    loss = 0.5 * critic_loss + actor_loss - 0.001 * entropy
    # There is no connection between the optimizer and the rest of the graph

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    initlocal = tf.local_variables_initializer()

    session.run([init, initlocal])

def update(self, session, epochs, batch_size, states, actions, log_probs, returns, advantages):
    """
    Update neural network with experience buffers
    ##############################################
    epochs: number of epochs to train neural network for
    batch_size: size of data batches used for training
    states: array of environment states
    actions: array of actions taken
    log_probs: log probability of actions
    returns: array of estimated advantages at given times
    advantages: array of advantages, calculated by different between predicted returns and estimated
    """
    # Clipping value for PPO
    clip = 0.2

    for e in range(epochs):

        for state, action, old_log_prob, return_, advantage in self.make_batches(states, actions, log_probs, returns, advantages):

            new_actions, value = self.forward(state, session)

            new_log_prob = np.log(new_actions[action])
            ent = entropy(actions)    # NOTE: from scipy.stats import entropy

            #ratio = np.exp(new_log_prob - old_log_prob)
            ratio = np.exp(np.mean(np.mean(new_log_prob - old_log_prob, axis=1), axis=1))

            a = np.mean(ratio * advantage)
            b = np.mean(np.clip(ratio, 1 - clip, 1 + clip) * advantage)

            actor_loss = - np.min([a, b])

            session.run(optimizer, feed_dict={actor_loss: actor_loss, return_: returns, self.env: state, entropy: ent})
```

Comment: I highly doubt that you do "effectively the same thing" somewhere else as this is just not valid Python code. There is no variable called `optimizer` in the scope of the `update` function; this has nothing to do with Tensorflow. If you want to access `optimizer` inside `update` you will either need to pass it as an argument, define it as an attribute of the class (i.e. `self.optimizer = ...` or define it as a global variable (not recommended).

Comment: BTW this also holds for several other variables in that function. It looks like you got the right idea with defining `self.env` as an attribute but for some reason you are not doing this with the other variables.

Comment: Thanks, I really don't know why I overlooked the use of self.somevar for each of the variables. After reformatting to include self it had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

**A)** I assume the two functions `__init__` & `update` are in the same class. If they are, do the following:

1) Add the keyword `self.` to the beginning of the `optimizer` in the `__init__` function:

And you get: `self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)`

2) Add the keyword `self.` to the beginning of the `optimizer` in the `update` function:

And you get: `session.run(self.optimizer, feed_dict={actor_loss: actor_loss, return_: returns, self.env: state, entropy: ent})`

**B)** If they are **not** in the same class, you have to pass `optimizer` as an argument to the `update` function.

And you get: `def update(self, session, epochs, batch_size, states, actions, log_probs, returns, advantages, optimizer):`